# How to create and append multiple dom elements efficiently

Tags: javascript, html, dom, domdocument, element

I'm building 10 buttons on the DOM and want to see if there is a more efficient way of building them because it seems strange to be calling `createElement` and `appendChild` 10 times.

```
<script>
function makeAlertButtons () {
  var container = document.createElement("div")
  container.setAttribute('id', "container")
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(container)
  for (var x = 1; x <=10; x++) {
    var butt = document.createElement("button")
    butt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(x))
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(butt)
  }
  document.getElementById("container").addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    alert(e.target.textContent)
  })
}
makeButtons()
</script>
```

Comment: Nope, what you're doing is fine, but you could move the appending of the container after the loop, that way you don't append to the actual document ten times when you append the buttons, you just add them to the container element in memory, and then append the whole thing to the DOM once.

Comment: It doesn't work when I move the appending of the container outside the loop because then it will only add the 10th button

Comment: But it's already outside the loop, right before, I'm just suggesting you do it after the loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize your code by reusing the container variable and moving

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(container);
```

after the loop

```js
function makeAlertButtons () {
  var container = document.createElement("div")
  container.setAttribute('id', "container")
 
  for (var x = 1; x <=10; x++) {
    var butt = document.createElement("button")
    butt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(x))
    container.appendChild(butt)
  }

  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(container);
  container.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    alert(e.target.textContent)
  })
}

makeAlertButtons();
```

Answer (score 0):

"more efficient"? It would be more efficient at execution time if the DOM was just built with HTML. If you want the JavaScript to be more efficient, then you'll want to cache your JavaScript in the Client's Browser, by using an external `<script type='text/javascript' src='yourJavaScriptPage.js'></script>` tag like that in your `<head>`. I'm including some code here that may teach you something:

```
var pre = onload, doc, bod, htm, C, T, E, makeAlertButtons; // if using technique on multiple pages change pre var
onload = function(){ // window.onload Event
if(pre)pre(); // if previous onload execute it

doc = document; bod = doc.body; htm = doc.documentElement;
C = function(e){
  return doc.createElement(e);
}
T = function(n){
  return doc.getElementsByTagName(n);
}
E = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
makeConsoleButtons = function(count){
  var container = C('div');
  container.id = 'container';
  for(var i=1,l=count+1; i<l; i++){
    var butt = C('input');
    butt.type = 'button'; butt.value = i;
    butt.onclick = function(){ // note lazy style will overwrite - but it's faster to type
      console.log(this.value); // alert can create problems in old IE
    }
    container.appendChild(butt);
  }
  bod.appendChild(container);
}
makeConsoleButtons(10);

} // end window.onload
```

Hope you learned something.

Comment: using `onload` is not really an example of efficiency. You should also use `var` when defining variables (for `doc`, ...). *"but it's faster to type"* is maybe not the best advice. It makes you get in that not-so-nice `pre` chaining, when there is `addEventListener`.

Comment: i don't get what you're assigning to pre, like everything? how does it work when you run pre()?

Answer (score 0):

I used this answer for another question but since basically they are same, I will post it here too.

Using an string to set `innerHTML` property on the element is the most efficient way to create multiple elements, because we will be deleting the creation of elements to the browser:

```js
const el = document.createElement('div');

el.innerHTML = `
<h1>Page Title</h1>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
<input value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet." >
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
`;

const root = document.querySelector('#app');
root.appendChild(el);
```

It is supported modern browsers. Faster than manually iterating over elements. Plus it is way more cleaner than creating those elements programmatically.

You can use an existing the element. Just select the element and insert the content:

```js
document.querySelector('#app').innerHTML = `
<h1>Page Title</h1>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
<input value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet." >
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
`;
```