# How to append (massively) multiple elements to the DOM using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, optimization

I have a table that must be filled dynamically by an asynchronous response from the API. The API sends back a JSON that is later interpreted into a row for the table, and I have it running perfectly.

The thing is, the bigger the JSON response is, the more times it takes to process the response (obviously), so when I go higher than 2k-3k elements in the array, the JS appending the rows to the table starts taking more than 20 min processing the JSON response.

Is there any way to optimize this?

Here's an example of my parsing process:

```js
function fillTable() {
    let tbody = $('tbody');
    for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        let tr = $('<tr><td>' + (i + 1) + '</td><td>Table row ' + (i + 1) + '</td><td>' + (Math.random() * 1000) + '</td></tr>');
        tr.appendTo(tbody);
    }
}
fillTable();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Obviously, the snippet doesn't reflect the amount of time it takes to process the JSON, but you get the idea.

Comment: Questions about optimization are more related to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Remove jQuery from the equation and add the rows at once (`tbody.insertAdjacentHTML(...)`, `tbody = document.createElement("tbody"); /*...*/ tbody.appendChild(row); table.appendChild(tbody);`, ...)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question presents a working example of code, and presents an approach to optimizing it.  Given that the original logic worked, and there are any number of ways to optimize this logic which promotes opinionated answer, this question is off topic for StackOverflow and would be better suited for a related site like [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) where refactoring would be on topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create and append multiple dom elements efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40186673/how-to-create-and-append-multiple-dom-elements-efficiently)

Comment: @GeorgeJempty The link with which the question is marked as possible duplicate is about 10 new elements. The answers proposed for that question would not solve the performance issues with 2k-3k elements.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v2o4bups/1/  Creating the html, and not parsing it, is much more efficient than having jQuery parse every row every iteration.

Comment: The reason it gets slower and slower is the way tables are rendered in browsers.  Because they resize to fit, every time you add a new row, the browser needs to check *every* cell.  You can improve this by: a) add all rows in a single append statement (rather than one row at a time) - this will still be slow if there's a lot of rows.  b) using divs instead of a table

Comment: @Niche This is a common question I'm sure there are other identicals, you should be googling first if you aren't already doing so

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I did, and that's why I answered my own question. I struggled a few hours with the solution, and wanted to share how I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to fix this is, instead of appending every row individually to the table, pushing each row element to an array, and after the array is complete, using the `apply` prototype function, extending the `append` jQuery function in order to apply the whole array at once.

Like this:

```
function fillTable() {
    let tr = [];
    let tbody = $('tbody');
    for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        let e = $('<tr><td>' + (i + 1) + '</td><td>Table row ' + (i + 1) + '</td><td>' + (Math.random() * 1000) + '</td></tr>');
        // Removed for better performance
        //tr.appendTo(tbody);
        tr.push(e);
    }
    $.fn.append.apply(tbody, tr).html();
}
```

Thus, reducing a 20-40 min process for 11k records, to about 7s.

Comment: A few things about this answer are confusing.  `tr` starts off as an array, but then the loop does `tr.appendTo(tbody)`.  `appendTo()` is a jQuery method, not an array method.  So that seems like a bug.  Also if you are simply pushing a new elment to an array `tr.push(e)` is much cleaner than constructing an entirely new array with `tr = [...tr, ...e];`.  And finally, `tbody` is a jQuery object.  `tbody.append(tr)` will append all the elements to the tbody.  `$.fn.append.apply(tbody, tr)` is over complicating the operation, and the following `html()` call is unused.

Comment: And if you wanted to get even more performance, you wouldn't do `$(html)` and just construct the html.

Comment: Sorry. Fixed it by commenting the appendTo() block. Appending the elements one by one greatly increased the HTML parsing process, which is what I fixed by calling `$.fn.append.apply` all at once. Does `tr.push(e)` perform better than `[...tr,...e]`? If so, I didn't know this and might change it in my code.

Comment: Why would constructing an entirely new array perform better than reusing the same array, pushing the new element?

Comment: I can't just construct the HTML, since it's a dynamic call to the API, which is itself called in several parts of the site. The same response is used to build other tables with different structures.

Comment: That... Actually... Sounds logical. I'm changing it right away.

Answer (score -3):

You can create a infinity loading and loading by step using pagination.

```js
function fillTable(page) {
    let tbody = $('tbody');
    for(let i = page; i < page + 50; i++) {
        let tr = $('<tr><td>' + (i + 1) + '</td><td>Table row ' + (i + 1) + '</td><td>' + (Math.random() * 1000) + '</td></tr>');
        tr.appendTo(tbody);
    }
}
fillTable(5);
```

but you need to have the control of scroll page